# How do I restart the standard output in assembly?

Tags: assembly, dos, dosbox

I am making a project in assembly on dos for school and I have this code which prints a counter in the game(on graphic mode):

```
    push ax
    mov cx,0
    mov dx,0
    mov ax,[counter]
    PushNumber:
        ; if ax is zero
        cmp ax,0
        je PrintNumber    
         
        ;initialize bx to 10
        mov bx,10       
         
        ; extract the last digit
        div bx                         
       ;push it in the stack
       push dx             
        
       ;increment the count
       inc cx             
        
       ;set dx to 0
        xor dx,dx       
        jmp PushNumber
    PrintNumber:
        ;check if count
        ;is greater than zero
        ;pop the top of stack
        cmp cx, 0
        je PrintZero
        pop dx
         
        ;add 48 so that it
        ;represents the ASCII
        ;value of digits
        add dx,48
         
        ;interrupt to print a
        ;character
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        
       ;decrease the count
        loop PrintNumber
        jmp exit_mdg
    PrintZero:
    mov dx, 48
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    exit_mdg:
    pop ax
ret 
endp multiDigPrint
```

but when I use it, every time the counter goes up it just adds to the previous number that was on the screen, so I end up with something like this: 01234... how do I reset the text everytime the counter goes up?

Comment: A standard trick is to output a carriage return (character code 0dh) so the cursor position goes back to the start of the line and subsequent output overwrites previous output.

Comment: The other way is to move the cursor to where you want to write the counter before you write it.